# Register a receiver to listen to the shake event

Tags: android, accelerometer

Can we Register a receiver to listen to the shake event ? Is there any receiver intent to do that ,I am not able to find it .
My requirement is to to launch my app on shaking the phone .

Comment: http://android.hlidskialf.com/blog/code/android-shake-detection-listener

Answer (score 1):

There is no receiver to get shake event. you have write this in service. To achieve this your app should run in background.

Answer (score 0):

You can register for the accelerometer sensor and look for spikes in the readings.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.All you have to do is implement the SensorListener interface.Then implement an algorithm that detects if movement of the phone is a shake or not.

[Check this out](http://android.hlidskialf.com/blog/code/android-shake-detection-listener)